How to go about furring irregular concrete wall
I have irregular Concrete stem walls that I would like to fur out for paneling. The walls vary in depth vertically and horizontally. Conceptually, I understand it is as simple as finding the furthest out point and furring everything else out to that before adding vertical furring strips. How to get there is the question.

You can see in the photo that I have marked the point that is the furthest out with a target.
Is there a vertical laser level that I could place on that point to determine how far out I need to fur everything in that plane? Any other strategies experienced folks can suggest?

Probably the best (easiest, least time consuming.) thing to do is to frame a wall out of 2x4s or 2x3s if you can find them in your location. Then set the frame against the concrete wall.
You lose a few inches, but save some sanity.

You can even frame with 2x2 plates and flat 2x4 or 2x3 studs and essentially lose no more space than you would with 2x2 furring.

In case RMDman's suggestion doesn't suit, here's how I'd go about mounting furring to the concrete. Any wood in contact with concrete should really be pressure-treated, though using something synthetic as your spacer shims would also do.

Determine the point at which the concrete extends furthest into the room. Plumb to the floor and mark it. Make a second mark into the room the thickness of your furring. This is your inside wall face location.

Extend the point across the floor to establish the inner wall face line. This could be found considering the concrete, or it could be found by squaring with other aspects of the room.

Transfer this line to the ceiling at both ends with a level, and snap a chalk line between.

Fasten horizontal furring to the floor and ceiling on your lines. Use 3" construction screws into framing and 2-3/4" concrete screws (or construction screws with plastic plugs) into concrete. Consider also using heavy-duty construction adhesive on the concrete.

Fit a vertical furring plank between the horizontal plates at one end of the wall. Fasten it to the plates with screws or nails.

Using a long straightedge or carpenter's line, move this board into a straight position (your primary concern being the face of the board, not the sides). Measure the gap behind it at 1/3 the wall's height. Cut a shim spacer to the appropriate size and mount the board at that point. Repeat at 2/3 the wall's height.

Repeat the previous step for a second vertical board at the opposite end of the wall.

Pull carpenter's lines horizontally between the two installed vertical boards at the 1/3 and 2/3 heights. You can use a single line and just wrap over four nails set in the boards' faces. Space the line off the boards using a convenient item such as nails or pencils. This allows you to work without affecting the strings. You now have a full wall plane established.

Set the rest of the furring strips to the lines on 16", 19.2", or 24" centers using the same item as a gauge between the string and the boards. Measure and cut spacers at each board-string intersection.


To clarify the reason for using a string spacer, it's difficult to set anything to a string without progressively moving the string. By leaving a gap you can be sure it stays where it belongs.
The reason we don't just plumb every board into position is because there's more chance of slight variation due to error. It can be difficult to hold several things perfectly in position while taking measurements, and even slight variation can result in a wavy or twisted wall. By using the same reference every time you minimize error.
I suggest installing the horizontal boards because you really want support at the top and bottom for your drywall or whatever. You can do without, but it sometimes results in undesirable waviness or flex.
